# Java: Unit Testing a method that returns an object

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, oop, junit

I am unsure how to unit test a method that takes in parameters as a string and returns an object based on that parameter. I cannot provide the method as the instructions I received was to use black box testing. (Method has bot been provided.)

Comment: Take a look at JUnit. Create a JUnit test case that executes the method with a variety of input data and checks that the returned object is correct for each input set.

Comment: Black box unit testing? What does it mean? Can you provide an example that illustrates your problem?

Comment: @defaultlocale https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing

Comment: @QBrute Never heard about that, thanks! Still, a code example might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would look at the different paths within that method. Then you write at least one testcase per path.

Each test uses those input parameters that should lead into the corresponding path, and asserts something about the output result that again matches the expectations for that path.

Coming from the black box side, you can do this in a similar way: but here you focus on the public contract of the method to determine the required tests.

And ideally you do black box first, and later you could measure coverage to ensure your method under test does not contain aspects overlooked by the black box approach. Or to find: my contract is fully tested; but still I am only utilizing 80% of the code in that method. Now you have to decide: is your understanding of the contract incomplete; or does the method contain 20% of code that should be deleted?!

In other words: this is more of a mindset thing: do you want to focus on guaranteeing that all possible paths were tested at least once - versus testing that the public contract works as expected  (which requires the availability of some form of specification!).